# Why the std::map::insert failed in the following example?

Tags: c++, c++11, insert, c++17, stdmap

Thanks to the good book *C++17 in detail* of *Bartlomiej Filipek*. I am discovering some examples which use `insert` in the context of `std::map`.

So I visited *cppreference.com* to have a better idea about how it works.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert

However, at the bottom of the page, there is a valuable and long example which gives us different examples of usage of `std::map::insert`.
I have tested it by myself on my computer to try to understand why with **overload 1** and **overload 4**, the insertion fails.

And honestly, I did not understand why.

I would grateful to you to explain what happens in those 2 specific examples (why the insertion fails), as it seems to be a very interesting example which uses at the same time the notion of "*structured bindings*".

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std::literals;

template<typename It>
void printInsertionStatus(It it, bool success)
{
    std::cout << "Insertion of " << it->first << (success ? " succeeded\n" : " failed\n");
}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, float> karasunoPlayerHeights;

    // Overload 3: insert from rvalue reference
    const auto [it_hinata, success] = karasunoPlayerHeights.insert({ "Hinata"s, 162.8 });
    printInsertionStatus(it_hinata, success);

    {
        // Overload 1: insert from lvalue reference
        const auto [it, success2] = karasunoPlayerHeights.insert(*it_hinata);
        printInsertionStatus(it, success2);
    }
    {
        // Overload 2: insert via forwarding to emplace
        const auto [it, success] = karasunoPlayerHeights.insert({ "Kageyama", 180.6 });
        printInsertionStatus(it, success);
    }
    {
        // Overload 6: insert from rvalue reference with positional hint
        const std::size_t n = std::size(karasunoPlayerHeights);
        const auto it = karasunoPlayerHeights.insert(it_hinata, { "Azumane"s, 184.7 });
        printInsertionStatus(it, std::size(karasunoPlayerHeights) != n);
    }
    {
        // Overload 4: insert from lvalue reference with positional hint
        const std::size_t n = std::size(karasunoPlayerHeights);
        const auto it = karasunoPlayerHeights.insert(it_hinata, *it_hinata);
        printInsertionStatus(it, std::size(karasunoPlayerHeights) != n);
    }
    {
        // Overload 5: insert via forwarding to emplace with positional hint
        const std::size_t n = std::size(karasunoPlayerHeights);
        const auto it = karasunoPlayerHeights.insert(it_hinata, { "Tsukishima", 188.3 });
        printInsertionStatus(it, std::size(karasunoPlayerHeights) != n);
    }

    auto node_hinata = karasunoPlayerHeights.extract(it_hinata);
    std::map<std::string, float> playerHeights;

    // Overload 7: insert from iterator range
    playerHeights.insert(std::begin(karasunoPlayerHeights),
        std::end(karasunoPlayerHeights));

    // Overload 8: insert from initializer_list
    playerHeights.insert({ {"Kozume"s, 169.2}, {"Kuroo", 187.7} });


    // Overload 9: insert node
    const auto status = playerHeights.insert(std::move(node_hinata));
    printInsertionStatus(status.position, status.inserted);

    node_hinata = playerHeights.extract(status.position);
    {
        // Overload 10: insert node with positional hint
        const std::size_t n = std::size(playerHeights);
        const auto it = playerHeights.insert(std::begin(playerHeights),
            std::move(node_hinata));
        printInsertionStatus(it, std::size(playerHeights) != n);
    }

    // Print resulting map
    std::cout << std::left << '\n';
    for (const auto& [name, height] : playerHeights)
        std::cout << std::setw(10) << name << " | " << height << "cm\n";
}
```

Comment: Something's missing here. When you use hinted insert, you need a call to lower_bound to get that iterator.

Comment: can you show the complete code? - something seems to be missing.

Comment: I sent the complete code for you.

Comment: @StevenSudit : please, what do you mean by "lower_bound"  ? It is the first time I come across "lower_bound" for std::map::insert

Comment: @skeller : I did it. Yes, it sounds better to have the complete code. I was not sure, if that's ok for the questions of copyrights, but I think, all is ok.

Comment: @D.K. *"it seems to be a very interesting example which uses at the same time the notion of "structured bindings"."* Keep in mind that, the question, has nothing to do with *structured bindings* here.

Comment: @JeJo : thank you for having edited and for having improved the presentation of my first message.

Comment: @D.K. It's kind of obsolete ever since C++17's insert_or_assign(), but there's an idiom when you use lower_bound() followed by a key comparison to do the equivalent of find(). Then, if it's not found, the iterator is used for the hinted insert.

Comment: @StevenSudit : it is what I was thinking. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated on the *[cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert)* the `std::map::insert`:

> Inserts element(s) into the container, **if the container doesn't**
>   **already contain an element with an equivalent key.**

In `// Overload 1`:

The iterator `it_hinata` is pointing to the lastly inserted entry which is `{"Hinata"s, 162.8}` and if you try to enter the same *key-value* pair, the insertion fails and hence `success2 == false`.

In `// Overload 4`:

The iterator `it_hinata` is still pointing to the same (firstly) inserted *key-value* pair(i.e. same `{"Hinata"s, 162.8}`). Therefore, the same reason in the above case, insertion fails. That means, the size of the map(i.e. `karasunoPlayerHeights`) remains the same after the insertion call, and the condition `std::size(karasunoPlayerHeights) != n`  evaluated to `false`.

Following is the [minimal, complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from what OP posted:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std::literals;

template<typename It> void printInsertionStatus(It it, bool success)
{
    std::cout << "Insertion of " << it->first << (success ? " succeeded\n" : " failed\n");
}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, float> karasunoPlayerHeights;

    // Overload 3: insert from rvalue reference
    const auto [it_hinata, success] = karasunoPlayerHeights.insert({ "Hinata"s, 162.8f });
    printInsertionStatus(it_hinata, success);    
    {
        // Overload 1: insert from lvalue reference
        const auto [it, success2] = karasunoPlayerHeights.insert(*it_hinata);
        printInsertionStatus(it, success2);
    }
    {
        // Overload 4: insert from lvalue reference with positional hint
        const std::size_t n = std::size(karasunoPlayerHeights);
        const auto it = karasunoPlayerHeights.insert(it_hinata, *it_hinata);
        printInsertionStatus(it, std::size(karasunoPlayerHeights) != n);
    }
    // Print resulting map
    std::cout << std::left << '\n';
    for (const auto& [name, height] : karasunoPlayerHeights)
        std::cout << std::setw(10) << name << " | " << height << "cm\n";
}
```

which outputs:

```
Insertion of Hinata succeeded
Insertion of Hinata failed
Insertion of Hinata failed

Hinata     | 162.8cm
```